How to Extract Text in Row-wise Format Using flutter_tesseract_ocr and google_mlkit_text_recognizer in Flutter?
I am working on a Flutter project where I need to perform text recognition on images/PDF. I want to compare the results of using flutter_tesseract_ocr and  google_mlkit_text_recognizer. I am having trouble integrating both libraries in my Flutter app and need some guidance. i want to get data in row wise. i have attached images for recognizing.
Here is flutter_tesseract_ocr output :-
enter image description here
Here is google mlkit text recognizer output :- enter image description here
What I've Tried
I've checked the documentation for both libraries but couldn't find specific information on formatting the output text row-wise.
I've also searched online for examples but haven't found a solution that works for my case.enter imaenter image description herege description here
What I Expected
I expected to get the recognized text in a row-wise format, meaning each line of the text in the image should be printed or stored separately, making it easy to process further.
What Actually Happened
google_mlkit_text_recognizer: The text is recognized, but I am not sure how to format it row-wise. The output is line-by-line within each block, but I need to ensure it's row-wise across the entire image.
flutter_tesseract_ocr: The text is recognized as a single string, making it hard to differentiate between rows.
Specific Issues
How can I format the recognized text row-wise using google_mlkit_text_recognizer?
Is there a way to format the text output row-wise using flutter_tesseract_ocr?
Are there any best practices or additional steps to ensure the text is recognized and formatted correctly in a row-wise manner?
Additional Information
Flutter version:  3.19.1
Dart SDK version: 3.3.0
google_mlkit_text_recognizer version: latest
flutter_tesseract_ocr version: latest
Platform: Android/iOS
